# No message on buttonClick discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I click on button I get error "Interaction failed"
This is full code I have written.
What could be wrong here? I tried and interaction.create but no luck so far. Thank you.

Index.js

```
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const {gabriel} = require('./commands/gabriel.js')

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  });

  client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.content === "$gabriel") {
        gabriel(message);
    }

});

client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
  if(button.id === "11"){
    await button.reply.defer()
    await button.message.channel.send("Skills are posted in here!")
  } else if (button.id === "12"){
    await button.reply.defer()
    await button.message.channel.send("Constellation Data!")
  }
});

  client.login(token);
```

Comment: Do you use some extra npm packages or where does `clickButton` come from? I don't think discord.js has a `clickButton` event.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, there isn't an event called `clickButton` in `discord.js` unless you use extra npm packages such as `discord.js-buttons`. You can check the list of all the events at [discord.js | Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client). To execute a piece of code when a button is clicked, you would have to create a [`messageComponentCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction) in the channel of your choice by doing:

```js
var filter = (click) => click.user.id === message.author.id; // Creating a filter to only allow some users to click the button
const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
  time:
    1000 *
    10 /* Choosing how long the collector can work. (The time is in milliseconds) */,
  max: 1 /* Defining the maximum number of clicks on the button */,
  filter: filter /* Applying the filter */,
});
collector.on('collect', (click) => {
  // Execute some code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For discord.js v13, `clickButton` is not an event. You need to use `onInteraction` then check if the interaction is a button.

For example:

```
client.on('interaction' (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isButton()) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```